# Is there a way to check a diagonal of a 2 dimentional array in Python which has a variable size?

Tags: python, math, matrix, multidimensional-array, game-development

I am currently programming a Connect N game in Python based on a Connect 4 logic (the game where you need 4 pieces in a row to win). I coded basically the Connect 4 function but having some hard time to make it work with an n-dimension win condition.

I need to basically check for horizontal, vertical, positive slope, and negative slope diagonals which have 4 of the same pieces in a row. For my Connect 4 logic I have the following:

```
def winning_move(board, player_number):
    # Check horizontal locations for win
    for c in range(COLUMN_COUNT-3):
        for r in range(ROW_COUNT):
            if board[r][c] == player_number and board[r][c+1] == player_number and board[r][c+2] == player_number and board[r][c+3] == player_number:
                return True

    # Check vertical locations for win
    for c in range(COLUMN_COUNT):
        for r in range(ROW_COUNT-3):
            if board[r][c] == player_number and board[r+1][c] == player_number and board[r+2][c] == player_number and board[r+3][c] == player_number:
                return True

    # Check positively sloped diaganols
    for c in range(COLUMN_COUNT-3):
        for r in range(ROW_COUNT-3):
            if board[r][c] == player_number and board[r+1][c+1] == player_number and board[r+2][c+2] == player_number and board[r+3][c+3] == player_number:
                return True

    # Check negatively sloped diaganols
    for c in range(COLUMN_COUNT-3):
        for r in range(3, ROW_COUNT):
            if board[r][c] == player_number and board[r-1][c+1] == player_number and board[r-2][c+2] == player_number and board[r-3][c+3] == player_number:
                return True
```

With my limited knowledge, I thought about having a for loop to iterate with, but I can't have a for loop as a condition to an if. So I thought that there might be a way to check for a certain range of a matrix but couldn't find anywhere yet how I would do it.

Is there a way to basically check for a range window inside a matrix without using for loops?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

We can solve such problems using recursion, where the function recursively checks for the condition for the next element in the matrix, i.e. if the player has a winning move. Following is a working code, which works on a 2D array or matrix of any size. The output is also shown after the code.

```
def winning_move_new(my_board, player_number):

    num_rows = len(my_board)
    num_cols = len(my_board[0])

    found_win = False

    if findAdjacentElementsMatch(my_board, player_number, num_rows, num_cols, "row_search"):
        found_win = True

    if findAdjacentElementsMatch(my_board, player_number, num_rows, num_cols, "col_search"):
        found_win = True

    if findAdjacentElementsMatch(my_board, player_number, num_rows, num_cols, "diag_search"):
        found_win = True

    if findAdjacentElementsMatch(my_board, player_number, num_rows, num_cols, "neg_diag_search"):
        found_win = True

    return found_win

def findAdjacentElementsMatch(board, player_number, num_rows, num_cols, search_type):

    if search_type == "row_search":
        for row in range(num_rows):
            if isNextElementAlsoMatching(board, player_number, num_rows, num_cols, search_type = "row_search",
                                         next_row = row, next_col = 0):
                print("Found row matching at row=", row)
                return True

    elif search_type == "col_search":
        for col in range(num_cols):
            if isNextElementAlsoMatching(board, player_number, num_rows, num_cols, search_type = "col_search", 
                                         next_row = 0, next_col = col):
                print("Found column matching at column=", col)
                return True

    elif search_type == "diag_search":
        if isNextElementAlsoMatching(board, player_number, num_rows, num_cols, search_type = "diag_search", 
                                     next_row = 0, next_col = 0):
            print("Found diagonal matching")
            return True

    elif search_type == "neg_diag_search":
        if isNextElementAlsoMatching(board, player_number, num_rows, num_cols, search_type = "neg_diag_search", 
                                     next_row = num_rows-1, next_col = 0):
            print("Found negative-diagonal matching")
            return True

    return False

def isNextElementAlsoMatching(board, player_number, num_rows, num_cols, 
                              search_type, next_row = 0, next_col = 0):

    if (next_row >= num_rows or next_col >= num_cols or
        next_row < 0         or next_col < 0):
        return True # The last recursive step

    else:
        if (search_type == 'row_search'):
            # Row-search looks for entries in the next column within the same row
            return (board[next_row][next_col] == player_number and 
                    isNextElementAlsoMatching(board, player_number, num_rows, num_cols, search_type, 
                                              next_row, next_col+1))

        elif (search_type == 'col_search'):
            # Column-search looks for entries in the next row within the same column
            return (board[next_row][next_col] == player_number and 
                    isNextElementAlsoMatching(board, player_number, num_rows, num_cols, search_type,
                                              next_row+1, next_col))

        elif (search_type == 'diag_search'):
            # Diagonal-search looks for entries with the same row,col indices
            return (board[next_row][next_col] == player_number and 
                    isNextElementAlsoMatching(board, player_number, num_rows, num_cols, search_type,
                                              next_row+1, next_col+1))

        elif (search_type == 'neg_diag_search'):
            # Negative-diagonal-search looks for entries in the reverse-diagonal
            return (board[next_row][next_col] == player_number and 
                    isNextElementAlsoMatching(board, player_number, num_rows, num_cols, search_type,
                                              next_row-1, next_col+1))


my_board = [[12, 12, 14, 12],\
            [19, 12, 12, 17],\
            [12, 12, 12, 12],\
            [12, 12, 15, 12]]

player_number = 12
winning_move_new(my_board, player_number)
```

Output of this code for the above matrix is:

```
Found row matching at row= 2
Found column matching at column= 1
Found diagonal matching
Found negative-diagonal matching
```